# How to make a dump of my iPhone so as to make forensics

Tags: iphone, security, encryption, malware, ios

I would like to be able to run a forensic analysis on my iPhone from a disk dump copy made on my Mac or any kind of Unix as I would from any external disk with a `dd` command.

For those who are curious: why do I want to perform such a forensic analysis?
I would like to detect malware, data leaks, to check what is encrypted, what isn't…, this is a method I would like to be able to
run easily and as frequently as I need as a security audit.
I only trust what I understand!

I am open to any software method I can replay.

How may I proceed to see my iPhone as a normal disk?

How may I decrypt the dump obtained since I know my password, but not how is built the AES key from it?

Answer (score 3):

You can read about how the encryption is performed and how the AES keys are built in Apple's iOS Security Guide:

https://www.apple.com/business/site/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf

In particular this describes that the key is not available to the application processor. It is only available within the Secure Enclave. This means that even though you know your password, you cannot rebuild the AES-key from it on a different computer.

This means that it is not possible to do what you want (i.e. dumping the raw disk contents and decrypting it on another computer using AES keys that you build from your own password on that computer).

In regards to dumping raw disk content, you can use the dd command if you want - but you cannot really use it for anything.

Comment: Professional firms do offer to do forensic work on ios devices.

Comment: @historystamp: absolutly right. This is the only publicly aknowdledged skill. I hope this secret won't stay protected in the hands of Apple, state agencies and cyber-criminals.

Comment: @historystamp Working on the physical iOS device vs. a dd image of it are two entirely different things.

Comment: @dan I’m not protecting a secret to leave information only in the hands of a bad guys, nor am I saying that forensics is not possible. However you asked about a very specific way of doing things, and I answered with the facts - namely that you cannot do it like that. You will either need the information from the Secure Enclave (or interaction with the Secure Enclave) - and then you’re not doing it fully on another computer, or you’ll need to crack the encryption algorithm used in general - which is probably not that likely to happen.

Comment: There’s plenty ways of copying information off iPhones if that’s what you like to do, but it can’t be done like you describe. Note that those methods will not let you examine what’s encrypted and what isn’t - because all your user data is encrypted, but with various keys/methods that can vary on a file by file basis. If you read the files at a very high level, they will already have been decrypted.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to get your hands dirty. Presuming its an iPhone that you won't necessarily be using again...

You'll need to disassemble the phone, removing the flash parts (the disk as most people call it).  You must do this carefully since you will need to replace the flash parts and Secure Enclave such that they do not become unpaired with each other.

Copying the raw contents of the flash parts will allow you to review whether anything is stored in plain text, but I can save you the trouble...everything on the business side of the Secure Enclave is encrypted.

If you've been very careful, you can boot the phone and try to access known data. You'll want to have a logic analyzer on both sides of the Secure Enclave so that you can see what it got from which part of the flash. Pinouts for the flash parts are well known, but the BGA layout for Apple's custom ASIC are somewhat nebulous.

With considerable effort, you can for different data patterns to be read, but if your fake responses are too wrong, a bus error is generated and the entire thing stops working until you remove power and have another go.

Honestly, it's just not worth it unless somebody will pay you millions for the data you retrieve. Playing around with a broken phone just to feed your curiosity is one thing, but you will need serious EE skills and equipment to do forensics on an iPhone.

Comment: I am in search of a method I will run on "my iPhone". I don't want to destroy it .

Comment: Dan, I don't believe there's any possible way to run an application on an iPhone and retrieve the raw disk contents. Even if you have the password (as the legitimate user of the phone), other salts are used for the encryption, and some regions the Secure Enclave will not allow you to retrieve. Without tearing the phone apart, you MUST go through the Secure Enclave. Apple has explicitly ensured that there is no command that can be issued to read or write raw blocks (as you would with a command like dd). A hardware solution is required to do what you're after. That's by design.

Comment: BTW, even with a jailbreak, you can't bypass the Secure Enclave. Perhaps you should get an Android.